# Jackson enum deserialization. Spring restTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, enums, jackson

I'm added an enum type and variable to one of my classes.
Have a spring boot tests written which are using this class.

Once the enum was added, `jacksonMapper` isn't able to convert the class (for the `restTemplate` POST request).

Here is the error:

```
2016-11-17 11:36:11.571  WARN 10000 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.springapp.models.common.Condo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6393fabb; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.springapp.models.common.Condo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6393fabb; line: 1, column: 2]
2016-11-17 11:36:11.639  INFO 10000 --- [           main] c.s.controllers.api.CondoControllerTest  : status: 400
2016-11-17 11:36:11.639  INFO 10000 --- [           main] c.s.controllers.api.CondoControllerTest  : message: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.springapp.models.common.Condo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6393fabb; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.springapp.models.common.Condo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6393fabb; line: 1, column: 2]
```

the **class:**

```
public class Condo {

   **irrelevant fields**

    public Condo(LocationType locationType) {
        this.locationType = locationType;
    }

    public enum LocationType {
        CONDO("condo"), MALL("mall"), STATION("station");

        private String value;

        private LocationType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String stringValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    public LocationType getLocationType() {
        return locationType;
    }

    LocationType locationType; 
    ** getters/setters**
}
```

i also tried to use `@JsonCreator, @jsonValue` as it is pointed at some other SO threads. Doesn't help,

request:

```
Condo condo = new Condo(Condo.LocationType.CONDO);
** setting fields for condo object ** 

//CREATE
ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(controllerPath+"/add_active", condo, JsonResponse.class);
```

Comment: mark ==>  public static enum LocationType {..} and add a default constructor for 'Condo'

Comment: And what is JsonResponse? It seems the problem is more likely caused by deserialization of the response: 'Can not construct instance of com.springapp.models.common.Condo' and not when sending the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your controller code if you don't have `Condo` as input parameter. From the log it seems so. Jackson cannot deserialize the HTTP representation of `Condo` because it does not have default constructor.